# Asking about specific term of software implementation

Tags: discussion

Can I ask about Barium Meal Test or Canary Trap implementations samples in this site? Or should I asked in StackOverFlow.com? Or none of them?

Comment: Ask *what* about those samples? There are many on-topic and off-topic questions you could ask about any piece of code.

Comment: @Ixrec Just samples! Idea of how implement them

Comment: Okay, that would probably be considered either a "write code for me" request or a "recommend an off-site resource" request, both of which are considered off-topic on all SE sites that I know of.

Comment: Also, the Canary Trap/Barium Meal Test is *not an algorithm*, so it doesn't really make sense to ask for a software implementation of it.